# How to set the "getelementbyid" value to a div id using a button inside that div id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have about 300 div's of content, I need to be able to hide the current div and show a new div based on its id when the button is clicked. Most are set up  to flow one after the other, and some of them loop back to previous or future div tags based on which button you click. each previous div needs to be hidden, and each new div needs to be shown onclick. I can lay out each individual function, but I would rather set up a script or function to set the getelementbyid div id to hide and the div id to show so it can set onclick and I dont end up using 300+ functions

HTML Code

```
<div id="myDIV" >
<p>Sample Text Goes Here</p>
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(); myFunction2();">
Next</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" style="display:none">
<p>Next sample Text Goes Here</p>
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(); myFunction2();">
Back</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2(); myFunction3();">
Next</button>
</div>
</div>....
```

Javascript Code

```
function myFunction(){var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (x.style.display === "none") {x.style.display = "block";} else {x.style.display = "none";}
}
function myFunction2() {var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
if (x.style.display === "none") {x.style.display = "block";} else {x.style.display = "none";}
}
function myFunction3() {var x = document.getElementById("myDIV3");
if (x.style.display === "none") {x.style.display = "block";} else {x.style.display = "none";}
} 
function myFunction4() {var x = document.getElementById("myDIV4");
if (x.style.display === "none") {x.style.display = "block";} else {x.style.display = "none";}
}
```

for clarity this script is under my div tags, in the body portion of the page.
Any tips or help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the div's id's as a parameter

```
<div id="myDIV" >
     <p>Sample Text Goes Here</p>
     <div>
         <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('myDIV', 'myDIV2');">
         Next</button>
      </div>
</div>

//  1 method for all divs
function myFunction(currentID, nextID) {
    var  currentDIV = document.getElementById(currentID);
    var  nextDIV = document.getElementById(nextID);
    currentDIV.style.display = "none";
    nextDIV.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I attempted this code in my project and got this error code back:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry. Copy & Paste mistake. I corrected the code.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is such a simple solution, I don't know why I didn't see it before. This worked like a charm and saved a lot of time.